# How does profiling work in Chrome's developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dgrid

I'm trying to debug a performance issue with dgrid. I used Chrome to "Record JavaScript CPU Profile" and then clicked the most time-intensive function's file, leading me to this function block:

[image]

The function is certainly being called thousands of times, but

1. What is taking 12 seconds here? Is it saying that determining the truthiness of `contentNode` and `headerTableNode` is expensive or that the code *inside* the if block is expensive?
2. Why is Chrome think this line is so expensive compared to the others?
3. What does it mean that `resize` is only 1.9ms if statements within `resize` take longer than that?

Comment: Profiling shows the actual computation time, that was spent on your function. By the way, check `inherited()` function ... The time of "children" functions can be included in the time of the "parent" function (because of inlining)

Comment: Any function can take any amount of time, if you execute it often enough.

Comment: @IvanKuckir `this.inherited()` doesn't even have a time on it. You're saying its timing is bundled into the if block??

Comment: Yes, if you are calling a short function, Javascript engine replaces the function call with an actual content of that function (that is called inlining). Then, the execution time of inherited() is included in the execution time of resize()

Comment: @IvanKuckir you mean the execution time of `resize()` that's only 1.9ms? If you're able to decipher what the numbers in my image mean, feel free to type up an answer explaining them.

Comment: Out of those12 seconds, resize may take only 1 second and inherited() takes 11 seconds. You should analyze the inherited() function, too.